# downloaded assetbundle is not in Application.streamingAssetsPath

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I get the assetbundle by using `UnityWebRequest GetAssetBundle(string uri, uint version, uint crc);`

but `Application.streamingAssetsPath` is empty....

where is downloaded assetbundle and how to loaded downloaded assetbundle?

my Unity version is 2017.3

---

Thank you vmchar. but I don't know how to use

AssetBundle manifestBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(manifestBundlePath);
AssetBundleManifest manifest = manifestBundle.LoadAsset("AssetBundleManifest");
What is manifestBundlePath and How to access this path.

How can I access downloaded assetbundles before use UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle

if you suggest the way, I'm really thanks to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity's Asset Bundles are not downloaded into streamingAssets folder, they are downloaded to Cache, you can read about it [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Caching.html). This Cache path is unique for each platform, and Unity's API incapsulates paths in Cache class. You should also keep in mind that user can delete all downloaded bundles from Cache by cleaning application resources (it's done in system setting on mobile platforms). Also this [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.html) may be helpful.